# Can't get runtime to allow class in java.util

Tags: java, securitymanager

I recently wanted to create my own copy of `GregorianCalendar` to add some `System.out.println` to help me understand how it works.  I copied the source and renamed the class, but it wouldn't compile because the source references package-private names in other classes.  So I tried adding `package java.util;` to the source and putting it in a `java\util` subdirectory of my working directory.  I got the program to compile, but it is throwing `java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util`.

After reading through the tutorial on Security, I tried running `policytool` to give myself permission to define a class in `java.util`.  I now have a file `policy1` that looks like:

```
grant {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "defineClassInPackage.java.util";
};
```

(plus the DO NOT EDIT comment).  This is in my work directory, same as my test program.  I ran (in a Command Prompt window):

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=policy1 Test35
```

But it's still not working.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:659)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at Test35.main(Test35.java:13)
```

Did I do something wrong, or miss a step?

Comment: You might have better luck loading it in an IDE, and just setting breakpoints.

Comment: @Gus There are some debugging jobs for which debuggers are not appropriate.  Say I wanted to run a program to call one of the methods a few hundred times.  What would you prefer to do ... gather a few hundred lines of output in a file that could perhaps be processed with a script, or sit there waiting to hit Continue Continue Continue hundreds of times in a debugger?  Anyway, I no longer actually need to look at the class, but I want to know how to get this kind of thing to work for next time.

Comment: why does it need to be in java.util? If its your own copy of the class you should create it in your own package.

Comment: @yate As I explained in my question ... if it's not in `java.util` then it won't compile because it relies on symbols with package visibility.

Comment: Even then, I'm pretty sure you can set up breakpoint actions that also log in eclipse.  http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_brk_action.htm

Comment: ever get a solution to this?

Comment: @adapt-dev no, I didn't.